# setContentView says source not found

Tags: android, layout, view, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am trying to have a custom GLSurfaceView with some text over it, to display the score in a game. I have made a uniform xml layout based off of someones post here but when I try to load it with a setContentView the app crashes. after debugging I found that it says "Source can not be found". I have rebuilt the R file but that doesn't help. For reference my class that extends GLSurfaceView is called GLView. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 package org.kizik.WLTBO;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;




    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class WholettheballoutActivity extends Activity {
       GLView view;



       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.score);
          view = (GLView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);

       // You can use a FrameLayout to hold the surface view
          /*FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
          frameLayout.addView(view);

          // Then create a layout to hold everything, for example a RelativeLayout
          RelativeLayout relativeLayout= new RelativeLayout(this);
          relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
          relativeLayout.addView(score);
          setContentView(relativeLayout);*/
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPause() {
           super.onPause();
           view.onPause();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           view.onResume();
       }
    }
```

With the XML file name score.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <org.kizik.WLTBO.GLView
        android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>        

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may happen if you have created a constructor  with single parameter GLView(Context c) , you need to create another constructor like this GLView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs), so if u havent created that constructor, then it can not not find the GLView from class, coz its constructor is not created..!! i think you havent created that constructor..!!

```
 public GLview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

   super(context,attrs); }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This took forever with me trying random things. That did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your custom view's XML declaration, it should be something like this:

```
 <org.kizik.WLTBO.GLView [other attributes]/>
```

Comment: That did not work either, I will update to show what it looks like.